# How to map 3D spherical point configuration (not the earth) onto 2D plane?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d, projection, matplotlib-basemap

I have a 3d spherical point set of 10 points, (2 layers of pentagonal loudspeaker array) **[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aDiY.png)**. I want to obtain 2D representation of this configuration. (Mollweide, Mercator, Cylindirical or Equirectangular projection?)
I will set the axis so that they give corresponding elevation and azimuthal angles. An example is given in **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWNss.png)** (Taken by ALLRADecoder vst plugin by IEM)

Is there a way to do this with a Python package like matplotlib, mayavi, or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually render something similar to above, you might want to look at [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/index.html) however it might not be the most intuitive package to dive into.

If you want to just get the 2d set of points this 3d object makes you could just look at doing some [projection maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)) and then a package like [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) would be ideal for plotting this 2d representation and is quite user-friendly if you're new to python and graphics.